# Get license for InfoPath form services

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365, forms-services

We get this message:

> Sorry, you don't have a license to use InfoPath Forms Services. Please contact your help desk

How can I get license to use InfoPath for services?

Comment: check your office service that is InfoPath service available to that package or not. And if it is yes then follow the [post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx).

Comment: As far as I know you have to have a SharePoint Enterprise license to use InfoPath Form Services. You can update your key for the SharePoint Farm via the Central Administration under "Upgrade and Migration".

Comment: Office 365 Small Business Premium month by month Plan , i am new deveper in this plateform and the sharepoint administrator have no idea to get this license , so i haven't Privilege to go to central Administration .

Answer (score 1):

As you are on **Office 365 Small Business Premium**, this plan does not include the Infopath Form service. This is enterprise feature and you have to buy the different subscription.

InfoPath Forms Services is supported by Office 365 Enterprise **E3/E4/A3/A4/G3/G4/K1** for Government plans. Please check this: [SharePoint feature availability across Office 365 plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_tableo365)